# Why doesn't the fact we can force the continuum hypothesis outright prove the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Nick Weaver's *Forcing for Mathematicians* and in Chapter 12 ("Forcing CH") he starts with this (pg 45 - 46):

(Everything here is relativized to $M$ - which in his book is a model of ZFC).

Let $P_1$ be the set of all partial functions from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\aleph_1$ (which is a forcing notion) and let $G$ be a generic ideal of $P_1$. Since the elements of $G$ are functions that must be consistent (since $G$ is an ideal) you can take the union of them to construct a function $\tilde{f}$ from a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to a subset $\aleph_1$.

He then proves that:

- $\tilde{f}$ is a bijection (not just a function) from a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to a subset $\aleph_1$ since patching consistent bijections together gives you a bijection.
- The domain of $\tilde{f}$ is all of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ since $G$ is generic.
- The range of $\tilde{f}$ is all of $\aleph_1$ since $G$ is generic.

A far as I can tell therefore, given any model $M$ of ZFC (i.e. any set for which ZFC holds), there is a bijection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ to $\aleph_1$ and therefore the continuum hypothesis is true.

---

I know he goes on to talk about $M[G]$ but, as far as I can tell, any $M[G]$ is just another model of ZFC and could very well have been the set we picked for $M$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

But the bijection $\widetilde f$ is not in $M$, that's the whole point. It is in $M[G]$. What you've shown is merely that for every model of $\sf ZFC$, there is a larger model in which $\sf CH$ is true.

To see that indeed $\widetilde f\notin M$, note that given *any* function $g\colon \mathcal P(\Bbb N)\to\omega_1$, there is a dense set of conditions $p$ such that $p\nsubseteq g$. Therefore by genericity, $\widetilde f\neq g$. If $\widetilde f$ is not equal to any function in $M$, then it cannot be in $M$.

(This is, more broadly, the reason why whenever a forcing is nontrivial, there are no generic filters in the ground model.)

Comment: Technically, the forcing needs to be separative, not merely nontrivial, for generics to not live in the ground model. :P

Comment: @Noah: I use nontrivial in the broad sense here. Every condition has two incompatible extensions.

Comment: I know, but the OP might not be familiar with that.

Answer (score 7):

The key here is that $G$ is required to be generic over $M$, and as a consequence $G \not\in M$.

As you've noticed, if you can make a model of ZFC which contains $G$ and which agrees with $M$ about what $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\aleph_1$ are, then in that model CH will hold.  Forcing tells us how to build such a model, and hence shows us that given a model $M$ we can make a model where CH holds.  That lets us show the relative consistency of ZFC+CH, but it doesn't prove CH.

Answer (score 6):

Let me add a couple points to the existing answers:

---

First, there's a key point which has not been  mentioned in the existing answers: it's important to note that **generics do not always exist**. We are only guaranteed existence when $M$ is *countable*. So the statement

> Every $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a submodel of some $N\models\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$

isn't really true - we need to restrict to *countable* $M$s. Indeed, if $\mathsf{CH}$ is false in reality then there is some $M$ with no end extension satisfying $\mathsf{CH}$: namely, any model containing all the reals.

A couple side comments:

- "Every countable $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ is a submodel of some countable $N\models\mathsf{ZFC+CH}$" *is* true - we don't need these countable models to be well-founded! This isn't obvious, but isn't hard to show and is a good exercise in "running all the recursions internally."
- We *can* talk about forcing extensions of arbitrary models (and indeed $V$ itself!) via the **Boolean-valued model** approach to forcing. This is the approach taken in Jech, for example. However, while fascinating and important it's also in my opinion substantialy less intuitive than the poset approach.

---

Second, for pedagogical value let me give an example where the importance of $G\not\in M$ is more blatantly obvious, namely the Levy collapse $Col(\omega,\omega_1)$.

$Col(\omega,\omega_1)$ is the simplest forcing for making $\omega_1$ countable: it consists of finite partial functions $\omega\rightarrow\omega_1$, ordered by reverse extension as expected. Since for each $\alpha\in\omega_1$ the set $\{p: \alpha\in ran(p)\}$ is dense, a generic $G$ (or rather, the union of the conditions in such a $G$) is a surjection from $\omega$ to $\omega_1$.

More precisely, and restricting to countable transitive models for simplicity, we have:

> If $M$ is a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $G$ is $Col(\omega,\omega_1^M)$-generic over $M$ then $M[G]\models\omega\equiv\omega_1^M$.

But unlike $\mathsf{CH}$, it's obvious that we can't possibly have a "same model" phenomenon: there is no $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ such that $M\models \omega\equiv\omega_1^M$. So considering this example first may help you see why forceability **cannot possibly** imply truth in general.

---

Finally, let me end on a positive note. Despite the above, there *are* some times when the "forceability" of a sentence implies its outright truth:

- **Shoenfield's absoluteness theorem** says that the truth of $\Pi^1_2$ sentences cannot be changed by forcing, so if $G$ is generic over $M$ and $M[G]\models\varphi$ with $\varphi\in\Pi^1_2$ then $M\models\varphi$ and vice versa (actually Shoenfield says somewhat more than this, but meh). But this phenomenon is in general rare.
- For special models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ we can get stronger absoluteness results. Specifically, strong [large cardinal axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_cardinal) imply greater amounts of absoluteness (e.g. if I recall correctly, if $M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ + "There are infinitely many Woodin cardinals" then all projective sentences are absolute between $M$ and its generic extensions).

However, in general absoluteness is pretty rare and should certainly never be taken for granted.